# Identify an anime from a video

Tags: story-identification

What is this anime called? Is there a trailer?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **Omakase Scrappers**

[image]

I can't find any wikipedia page, and the closest thing to a trailer I could find is [the opening credit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS9EYYMd8WM)

It seems that the video in your question is from [Episode 35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5ajDN3VeeY)

If you want to do more research, [this website](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=2007) gives alternative titles :
**Leave it to scrappers!**
**Los Robotrabajadores** *(Spanish)*
**おまかせ　スクラッパーズ**　 *(Japanese)*

Comment: Did you know this already or did you research it?

Comment: @Valorum Research only, I've never heard of it before today

Comment: I'm curious... how did you go about researching it? I did some Google searches, but to little avail other than a *lot* of tickling fetish videos on Youtube. *shudder*

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I used the recommended/similar videos on youtube (on the right of the page). I first found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRh4A_e3eSw&t) but still no title or name and I then found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5ajDN3VeeY) whith the title in it. This is the same video duplicated, I just got lucky and identified the thumbnail.

Comment: @Lordofdark: That is useful information. Thank you.

Comment: @core You should [accept the answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), as it answers your question correctly.

Comment: @user137369 - I'm not the OP. [core](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/77704/core) is...

Comment: @Valorum Corrected. I mistook your edit on the top post.